# parse push notification ignoring default push callback class

Tags: android, push-notification, parse-platform

Notifications are arriving OK. the problem is when Notification is clicked is starting `TeamActivity` when `MainActivity` is set as default push callback activity:

```
/// Application class
PushService.setDefaultPushCallback(this, MainActivity.class);
```

In Manifest:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".TeamActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_team"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.panchicore.xxx.MainActivity" />
    </activity>
    <... other activities />
    <... service and receivers from pusher />
```

Push OK:

```
{
    "title": "Hello world",
    "alert": "Hola mundo",
    "push_hash": "2d799b605347b6aaeabb203ab1387601"
}
```

Got the callback on `TeamActivity` class not on `MainActivity` class.

Comment: Not getting your question properly??Can yo please expand write it properly.

Answer (score 0):

Change your manifest like following.

```
<application
        android:name="ParseApplication"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name=".ProjectActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".TeamActivity"
        </activity>

        <service android:name="com.parse.PushService" />

        <receiver android:name="com.parse.ParseBroadcastReceiver" >
            <intent-filter>


                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />  
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />


               <!--  <action android:name="MyAction" > -->

            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

Hope it will works.

Comment: what is exactly ProjectActivity you added?

Comment: @panchicore:This is my default main launcher activity.